# Difficulty reading an image

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, image-processing

I'm taking a image from my pc and trying to get the edges of the picture using canny method.
However, it is always showing the message that the image is not read though my path correctly.
I'm using visual studio for the same.

```
 #include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
 #include<iostream>
 #include<conio.h>
 using namespace cv;
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
cv::Mat imgOriginal;        
cv::Mat imgGrayscale;       
cv::Mat imgBlurred;         
cv::Mat imgCanny;          

 imgOriginal = cv::imread("C:\Users\deep\Documents\Visual Studio 
     2017\Backup Files\de2\image.png",IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | IMREAD_ANYDEPTH);          
      // open image

 if (imgOriginal.empty()) {                                          
       std::cout << "error: image not read from file\n\n";     
    _getch();                               
    return(0);                              
}

cv::cvtColor(imgOriginal, imgGrayscale, CV_BGR2GRAY);     

cv::GaussianBlur(imgGrayscale,imgBlurred,cv::Size(5, 5),                
    1.5);                             

cv::Canny(imgBlurred,         
    imgCanny,             
    82,                         
    164);                       


cv::namedWindow("imgOriginal", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);  
cv::namedWindow("imgCanny", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);     
cv::imshow("imgOriginal", imgOriginal);     
cv::imshow("imgCanny", imgCanny);

cv::waitKey(0);                

return(0);
```

}

Comment: you need to escape the backslashes: `"C:\\Users\\deep\\Documents\\Visual Studio 
     2017\\Backup Files\\de2\\image.png"`

Comment: Or use forward slashes.